# Are there other options to unzip a file in Ubuntu besides "unzip"?

Tags: ubuntu, compression

My sysadmin is unreachable right now, and I have a zipped file on the server that I would like to unzip...however, we don't currently have zip and unzip installed, and I don't have root access to install them...

Am I out of options entirely? Are there other things that can unzip this file?

Comment: Is tar not installed? `tar -x`

Comment: just tried tar -x file.zip and it seems to be doing something...

Comment: @spuder you should leave an answer in case this works, and i'll upvote ya

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I haven't tried this, **but**, there's a `zipfile` module in Python's standard library since version 1.6, and since version 2.6 has had an `extractall` method

You *should* be able to do something like:

1. Create a file with the following contents (editing it to fit your use case).
2. Save the file as "unzipfile.py"
3. Run with python unzipfile.py

And it'll extract `test.zip` to `/home/user/directory`.

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', "r") as z:
  z.extractall("/home/user/directory")
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9432315/167299

Alternatively, [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) contains an unzip "module", and if you could download and run the statically-linked BusyBox, then you could use that to unzip things.

Comment: i tried the first part of this and got: The program 'import' can be found in the following packages:
 * imagemagick
 * graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat - btw...i didn't downvote you

Comment: Oh.  You know you need to run it through Python?

Comment: Like, Type python, then run python, and type that into the interpreter.

Comment: ha no...i didn't know that....ill try that as well. (gives an idea of how new this is to me)

Comment: trying this now... i can't tell if its working or not....no errors, but simply outputs: '...' - is that standard for python?

Comment: Press enter a couple of times.

Comment: You should ditch trying to do this in interactive mode, copy the lines into a file, and run that with python.

Comment: WOW. looks like it worked....I stumbled thru successfully in interactive mode!

Comment: Welcome to Python.  It's awesome.

Comment: I tried this and it seemed like some file permissions got set incorrectly.

Comment: Neal: zip doesn't store file permissions. Tar does, on the other hand.

Comment: You can now just call the module directly from the command line `python -m zipfile -e monty.zip target-dir/` (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#command-line-interface)

Comment: awesome, only thing that worked for me!

Answer (score 18):

If you have `java` installed, the `jar` command can unzip a zipped file:

```
jar xvf file.zip
```

Note that you can install java without root access: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/linux/linux-jdk.html

Update: OpenJDK is downloadable for Linux as a `tar.gz` archive installable without root access here: http://jdk.java.net/17/

The Windows version is however a `zip` file so that wouldn't help on that OS...

Comment: Today I Learned.

Comment: The program 'jar' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * fastjar
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * gcj-4.5-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
Ask your administrator to install one of them :(

Comment: See my answer update.

Comment: I am a little scerred to install anything on the server, for fear of the wrath of my sysadmin, but i will definitely try this if need be.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there are other ways of unzipping the file on a system without `unzip`, but you could send the file to another linux system (with unzip installed or root access available), unzip the file there and - if necessary - send the unzipped file back to the original server.

The command to send a file from one server to another is `scp`. The syntax to send the file is:

```
scp <filename> <username>@<otherhostname>:<portnumber><fullpathtolocation>
e.g.: scp file.zip  user@server.example.com:2222/home/user/
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

**BSD / Mac OSX**

The tar utility that ships with Mac and BSD derivatives, support extracting zip archives from the tar command

```
tar -xvf foo.zip

tar --version
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
```

**Debian / RHEL**

The tar archive that ships with Ubuntu and others does not support extracting zip files. The best option will be to scp the file to a machine with zip installed.

```
tar -xvf foo.zip
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

---

**Smoke Test**

```
echo "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" > bar.txt
zip -r bar.zip bar.txt
rm bar.txt
tar -xvf bar.txt
cat bar.txt
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

---

**Update**

Rewrote answer to clarify that tar -xvf only works on bsd OS's. While it is good information, It will not work in this scenario after all.

Comment: what does the -zxvf do?

Comment: when i try that, i get tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header ... does that mean it failed, or still going?

Comment: `tar` ability to process zip files would be an extension Ubuntu tar (i.e. GNU tar) doesn't seem to provide. `-z` is for gzipped files, not zipped ones (unless it is a very recent extension).

Comment: does that mean if i upload a gzip it would work?

Comment: It will, but that's not your question ;-)

Comment: v = verbose so you can see what it is doing, In this case, z does nothing, I always hit it out of habit, f specifies which archive to use (not really needed)

Comment: @spuder, what `tar` version are you using and are you sure it understands zipped files ?

Comment: The z option is harmless on OSx if it isn't needed. Looks like on your system, you must omit the z or else you get the error "does not look like a  tar archive"

Comment: tar -xvf tokens.sql.zip came up with: tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: This answer doesn't apply to Ubuntu. It seems only OS/X tar (and perhaps *BSD's one) handles zip archives, none of the other Unix and Linux do.

Comment: tar (GNU tar) 1.26

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file to another machine, unzip, and copy back.

Answer (score 0):

If the server has Gnome running, use the archive utility

[image]

http://www.wikihow.com/Unzip-Files-in-Linux